# Using global variables in express / node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, global-variables, scope

Trying to find a solution, i found 4 solutions, but i would like to know which one is better / best practice. And why! :P

**1. Using req.app.get()**

```
// app.js

app.set('settings', { domain: 'http://www.example.org' });

// other file

console.log(req.app.get('settings'));
```

**2. Using req.app.settings (similar to above)**

```
// app.js

app.set('settings', { domain: 'http://www.example.org' });

// other file

console.log(req.app.settings.settings);
```

**3. Exporting app object so i can access app.get() without req object**

```
// app.js

app.set('settings', { domain: 'http://www.example.org' });
module.exports = app;

// other file

var app = require('../app');
console.log(app.get('settings'));
```

**4. Using a global variable. Probably bad idea but... isn't "settings" a global thing anyway? (I can avoid reusing it so i dont get scope problems)**

```
// app.js

settings = { domain: 'http://www.example.org' };

// other file

console.log(settings);
```

Comment: If I were to rate, 1, 2, 3, 4. Don't do 4 at all.

Answer (score 2):

Brief opinion:

**1. Using req.app.get()**

Here, we are defining accessor method (getter/setter) for global properties. So its syntactically correct and quite easy to understand.

**2. Using req.app.settings (similar to above)**

Here, we are defining setter, but not using getter to access value. IMO, not a good way. Also, its difficult to understand as well.

```
console.log(req.app.settings.settings);
```

**3. Exporting app object so i can access app.get() without req object**

Why, you need to import a file, if you can access it. It may be useful if you have a high dependency of `app` module(like,high number of global setting which you need), which is generally the case when building an application.

**4. Using a global variable. Probably bad idea but... isn't "settings" a global thing anyway? (I can avoid reusing it so i dont get scope problems)**
Not a good approach, as code is not maintainable in this case.

***IMO, priority is like: 1 > 3 > 2 > 4.***

Comment: I like 1 also, but you need a "req" object. Let's say you require a paginate.js in your routes. In your routes you have "req", but not in "paginate.js". so you end doing require('paginate')(req) ? Sounds bad to me...

Comment: thats what i mentioned. Its depend upon your requirement. As i mentioned, you can go with 3 if you have dependency of app module.